# tcl error for unmatched quote in dynamic generated list

Tags: tcl

I am parsing a dyanmic data using tshark command.
Then I use functions like split and lindex on the result of the tshark output.

```
set result [exec /usr/sbin/tshark -r $pcap_name -x -R "icmp" -c 1]
set result [split $result \n]





set line [lindex $result 3]
```

However there are many occasions the scripts stops with the following error "tcl unmatched open quote in list". I believe this has something to do with the list not being well-formed. Is there to convert the list into a well-formed list.

Comment: The result you get from split will be a well-formed list, so the problem is likely to be somewhere else.

Comment: `[split]` always creates a well formed list. However, each element of the list is a string which should be processed by list generating functions like `split` or `regexp` again. The error most likely comes from code not shown in the example above. Tcl error messages generates a stack trace. If you get that error again please post the stack trace here.

Comment: Can lindex be the culprit here?

Comment: @Sumit Trehan : Can you share the output of `result` ?

Comment: @SumitTrehan It's the place where the problem bites, but not the place where the mistaken processing occurs.